# manage_pages granted, but can't get accounts info

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Yesterday I developed a little script (app), where I was able to upload photos to a specific album of a fanpage while visiting this fanpage (with installed app) as a fan.

Yesterday it worked - today it still works. But then I just copied the files and created a new app. The only difference is, that all files lay on another server. I granted following permissions with my fanpage admin account to the app: manage_pages, publish_stream and offline_access.

Now I just want run following code:

```
<?php $userAccounts = $facebook->api('/' . _ADMIN_ID . '/accounts');?>
```

But I get all time the error msg, that a user access token is needed. When I remove /account like:

```
<?php $userAccounts = $facebook->api('/' . _ADMIN_ID);?>
```

then it works without a problem and I get the admin informations. When I check my privacy settings, it says that I've granted the permissions that I mentioned above.

Here is the code I run until the error appears:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
include_once('facebook/facebook.class.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => _APP_ID,
  'secret' => _APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
  'fileUpload' => true
));
$userAccounts = $facebook->api('/' . _ADMIN_ID . '/accounts'); 
?>
```

Again: This app has the manage_pages, publish_stream and offline_access permission and without '/accounts' I get all information bout my admin-account.

Any help would be very nice.

Thanks in advance,
Jurik

Answer (score 0):

Obviously when you are calling: `$facebook->api('/' . _ADMIN_ID);` you are getting the public info about that user just like calling:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/_ADMIN_ID
```

You said that you granted the `offline_access`? so use the *stored* access token with your calls:

```
$userAccounts = $facebook->api('/' . _ADMIN_ID . '/accounts?access_token=' . $stored_access_token);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "stored_access_token"? 

I got an app access token with "file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' . _APP_ID . '&client_secret=' . _APP_SECRET)" but it still says, that I need a "A user access token is required to request this resource."

Btw, the $facebook->api()-Call to get the app access token returns all time null.

I really do not get it. This app got the permissions (manage_pages, publish_stream and offline_access), I got app's access token and it still tells me bout a required access token :(

Comment: Maybe my scenario is not clear:

My fanpage admin account has granted following permissions "manage_pages, publish_stream and offline_access" and the app is included to this fanpage as a tab.

Now user B visits this fanpage and clicks on the tab. Now, serverside, the app should get all account info bout the fanpage admin - but this doesn't work.

Comment: Well - now I get an empty array - no error message anymore - when I do the call for '/_ADMIN_ID/accounts' ... I bet that's a FB bug. Because in my privacy options I can see that manage_pages is granted and there should listened 2 pages.

Btw - is this access token, that I get with '/_ADMIN_ID/accounts' permanent? That would help me in this case too.

Comment: And another misterious thing: my user b - that has no relationship with the fanpage admin gets an empty array ('/_ADMIN_ID/accounts') but user b is the owner of this app (no permissions granted). Now - user c - doesn't get an empty array, he gets an error that says "user access token is needed" ... I really do not know what's going wrong there at facebook.

Comment: @Jurik, the first time the *admin* of the page authorized your app you should've "stored" his `access_token` for later use. You can ask the admin to access the page tab and save the access token `if($facebook->getUser() == "ADMIN_ID")` save the `access_token`, do this once to get the `access_token` and save it and after that remove that code.

Comment: You could also check the admin flag in the `signed_request`'s page object and then authorize (if not already an app user) and store the `access_token`!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I save now the access_token for this page from my admin account. But another problem occured: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340949/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-photo-to-fanpage-album-without-publishing-it/7341184#7341184 - I guess that's a real bug and I can only fix it with a workaround.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it answered your question. I'll have a look at the other question.